# App crashes while inserting into file

Tags: java, android, file

I am developing an Android app for interepting calls. The call intercepting part works fine! but then when I try to save the call number into a file, the app crashes. I am not a pro in Android programming.

This is my Java classes:

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Incoming: "+incomingNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               ob.write(incomingNumber);
                break;
        }
```

ob is an object of MainActivity. write() is a public method in MainActivity. My MainActivity is as below: 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private boolean detectEnabled;

private TextView textViewDetectState;
private Button buttonToggleDetect;
private Button buttonExit;

public void write(String a) {

    try {
       File sdcard=getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File directory=new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFiles");
        directory.mkdir();
        File file=new File(directory,"CALLS.txt");
        FileOutputStream  fout=new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
        osw.append(a);
        osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What (exact) error do you get? Did you set the correct permission in the manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the proper permission added to your manifest
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

If you have it, then I suggest you not to use hardcoded slash like "\" or "/". Rather than this, use File.separator which will return you a String that represent file separator.

As an example, you could try to write te content to your file like this:

```
byte data[] = yourString.getBytes();
String path = "your path";
String name = "your file name";
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path+File.separator+name);
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following snippet to your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: Permission is there.. Still the message i get in log cat is FATAL EXCEPTION!

Comment: can u post the log ?